# Matrix which satisfies the polynomial $A^3+A^2+A-3I = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Suppose we have an $n\times n$ real, symmetric matrix $A$. If it satisfies the equation

$$A^3+A^2+A-3I = 0,$$

what can we say about $A$? Is it there more than one matrix of size  $n\times n$  which can hold this property?

What I am thinking about is to factor the LHS, which gives me $(A-I)(A^2+2A+3I) = 0$. By The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, we have $(x-1)(x^2+2x+3) = 0$. Since $A$ is real and symmetric, It has only real eigenvalues. Then we don't need to consider the term $x^2+2x+3$, which gives $x-1=0$. So $A-I=0$, and $A = I$. But I highly doubt this is the wrong approach.

Thank you so much for your help!

edit: I appreciate you guys who answered a lot. But Is there a way that does not need knowledge about minimal polynomials? Thank you again!

Comment: It will be helpful for you if you can write a line or two of your thoughts. Some theorems about characteristics polynomial or minimal polynomials may be useful places to start plus anything else you may be learning on real symmetric matrices. You may want to study the polynomial (its roots): $f(x) = x^{3} + x^{2} + x - 3$.

Comment: "The value of $\;A\;$"? What do you mean by that? Do you mean the value of all its $\;n^2\;$ entries? I don't think so...then **what**?

Comment: I think only the identity can have this property

Comment: Can you specify a size? The 1 by 1 matrix with the lone entry 1(also known as the real number 1) satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An annhilating polynomial for the matrix $A$ is

$(x^3+x^2+x-3)$ which can be facored as $(x-1)(x^2+2x+3) $

Note : $ (x^2+2x+3)$ has no real roots

So the minimal polynomial is one of the following

$(x-1), (x^2+2x+3), (x-1)(x^2+2x+3)$

But since $A$ is symmetric  so (orthogonally ) diagonisable and so the minimal polynomial is product of distinct linear factors which gives $(x-1)$ as the only possible minimal polynomial.

So $A=I$

Answer (score 2):

A must be the identity. We know that it's minimal polynomial needs to divide: $$x^{3}+x^{2}+x-3=\left(x-1\right)\cdot\left(x^{2}+2x+3\right)$$
The matrix is symmetric so its Characteristic polynomial needs to split over the field.
The minimal polynomial must divide it, so it also must split.
We know that $x^{3}+x^{2}+x-3$ and $\left(x^{2}+2x+3\right)$ don't split over R, so the minimal polynomial  must be x-1

Comment: I appreciate it a lot. But if there are other possible approaches besides using the concepts of minimal polynomials? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ddasf you can look up how to show that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic one. The minimal polynomial is simply the polynomial with the smallest degree which annihilates A